# Searching a JSON with NODEJS

Tags: node.js, json, database, html-helper, searchbar

i have been trying to implement a search bar. My idea is that the user can partially type the word and then i can pass the variable in the response so it is used in my EJS. I am not using SQL databases on purpose, as im trying to keep this site running only with JSON file as database. I have tried but cant seem to make it work. I have tried many ways.

let userSearch = (req.body.search)
let allProducts = data

```
let filteredProducts = allProducts.filter(x => x.title == x.title.indexOf(userSearch))






 console.log(allProducts), gives you this :
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Chicken and vegetables stir-fry',
        Ingredients: [
          '2 tbsp peanut oil',
          '3 Lilydale Free Range Chicken Breast, trimmed, cut across the grain into thin strips',
          '1 brown onion, cut into thin wedges',
          '1 red capsicum, deseeded, cut into thin strips',
          '250g button mushrooms or mushroom caps, sliced',
          '1 bunch broccolini, cut into 4cm lengths',
          '2cm piece fresh ginger, peeled, finely grated or chopped',
          '2 garlic cloves, finely chopped',
          '2 fresh birdseye chillies, deseeded if desired, thinly sliced',
          '2 tbsp salt-reduced soy sauce',
          '1 1/2 tbsp oyster sauce',
          '1 tbsp water',
          '100g bean sprouts, to serve',
          'Coriander leaves, to serve',
          'Cooked white rice or noodles, to serve'
        ],
        description: 'Delicious and nutricious',
        image: 'chickenAndVeggies.jpeg',
        belongsTo: 'maria@hotmail.com'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Chocolate fudge cake',
        Ingredients: [
          '2 150ml sunflower oil, plus extra for the tin',
          '175g self-raising flour',
          '2 tbsp cocoa powder',
          '1 tsp bicarbonate of soda',
          '150g caster sugar',
          '2 tbsp golden syrup',
          '2 large eggs, lightly beaten',
          '150ml semi-skimmed milk'
        ],
        description: 'What´s better than a choco cake?',
        image: 'chococake.jpeg',
        belongsTo: 'maria@hotmail.com'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Quiche Lorraine',
        Ingredients: [
          '1/8 tsp ground nutmeg',
          '1/4 tsp smoked paprika',
          '1/4 tsp black pepper, finely ground',
          '1/2 tsp kosher salt',
          '4 eggs, large',
          '1 3/4 cup half and half, (or equal parts whole milk and heavy cream)',
          '1 cup shredded cheese , (I used sharp white cheddar, but gruyere is classic)',
          '1/2 yellow onion,  diced',
          '1/2 lb thin strips of bacon,  chopped into 1/2 inch pieces',
          '1 pie crust, (1 frozen crust, or 1/2 recipe for double pie crust)'
        ],
        description: 'A delicious quiche',
        image: 'QuicheLorraine.jpeg',
        belongsTo: 'richmond@hotmail.com'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Fluffy pancakes',
        Ingredients: [
          '1 cup all-purpose flour',
          '2 tablespoons white sugar',
          '2 teaspoons baking powder',
          '1 teaspoon salt',
          '1 egg, beaten',
          '1 cup milk',
          '2 tablespoons vegetable oil'
        ],
        description: 'Easy to make, delicious to eat',
        image: 'fluffypancakes.jpeg',
        belongsTo: 'johnny@hotmail.com'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Carrot cake',
        Ingredients: [
          '2 cups (240g) all-purpose flour',
          '2 teaspoons baking powder',
          '2 teaspoons cinnamon',
          '2 teaspoons allspice ',
          '1/2 teaspoon salt',
          '4 large eggs',
          '2 cups (400g) granulated sugar',
          '1 1/4 cup vegetable oil',
          '3 cups loosely packed peeled and grated carrots'
        ],
        description: 'mmmm a dream!',
        image: 'carrot-cake.jpeg',
        belongsTo: 'richmond@hotmail.com'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Kitty kitty',
        description: 'Beautiful',
        Ingredients: [ 'kitty', ' nothing', ' test', ' test', ' test' ],
        image: 'image-1654609682017.jpeg',
        belongsTo: 'maria@hotmail.com'
      }
    ]
```

console.log(userSearch) gives you the input you typed in the search bar input, the one coming in the body. In this case I typed hello so:

hello

```
  console.log(filteredProducts) gives an empty array regardless
    []
```

This for example, returns an empty array even when copying the title exaclty.
Any good ideas on how to implement the search bar in this case?

P.S i don´t know Jquery yet i use simple JS with NodeJs. thanks!

Comment: JSON is a string format to represent JavaScript Objects. You generally only work with "JSON" when transitioning to or from a file, API, or other persisted string source. It is not clear what `req.body.search` is, why you need to convert to a string, or what `data` is. Can you add enough details to show what the data looks like?

Comment: Ok, so the only reason I stringify req.body.search is so I can use indexOf as it compares strings and the incoming input which is req.body.search (search being the name of the input on the search bar) is not a string

Comment: You still don't show an example of what exactly `req.body.search` *is*. If it is not a string, you likely do not want to covert it to a string representation of the JavaScript object that it is, but you should access the property that you need to search for. You need more details of what is actually in `req.body.search` and what is in `data`.

Comment: Hey, I have now posted console logs, I hope this helps. data is the json file once it is parsed and req.body.search Is to request the search property that travelled on the body of the request

Comment: `title.indexOf` will return a numerical index of where the first occurrence happens, and would never be equal to the title. [MDN String.prototype.indexof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: I just figured it out haha. solution:

let filteredProducts = allProducts.filter(x => x.title.toUpperCase().match(userSearch.toUpperCase()))